# Unity Rigidbody.Addforce Impulse

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо, чтобы объект `paddle` толкал объект `sphere` и второй получал импульс, после этого второй объект бы катился от импульса. То, что получается - это сфера, получающая постоянное ускорение.

```
private bool isCollisioned = false;
private int impulseCount = 1;

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isCollisioned && impulseCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 sphereVector = gameObject.transform.position;
            Vector3 paddleVector = _rootClass._paddleController.transform.position;

            directionVector = (sphereVector - paddleVector).normalized;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(
                x: directionVector.x * sphereSpeed,
                y: 0,
                z: directionVector.z * sphereSpeed,
                ForceMode.Impulse
                );
            impulseCount++;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.tag == "paddle")
        {
            isCollisioned = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь сделать самостоятельно то, что по умолчанию делает физический движок самостоятельно?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите жёстко указать точную скорость и направление вашего шара, то зачем вы добавляете силу к уже имеющейся, получая не прогнозируемую и скорость и направление?

```
directionVector = (sphereVector-paddleVector).normalized*sphereSpeed;
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(directionVector.x, 0, directionVector.z);
```

Comment: Поправил. как вы сказали. ничего не изменилось. Сфера продолжает катиться. прилипнув к ботику. а ожидается. что она будет отталкиваться от него.

Comment: У вас косяк и он не в опубликованном куске кода. isCollisioned всегда true, impulseCount  всегда равен 1 и paddleVector проверьте как обновляется.